# Listen on TCP feed with spring-integration

Tags: spring-integration

I want to connect to two different TLS encrypted TCP feeds and both read and send json data. The incoming that will ofcourse be processed somehow. It does not necessarily need to be processed in spring-integration but can be put in a queue or whatever.

I don't want to hardcode the host and ports because I get them during runtime from a REST API that I am calling.

What I send won't necessarily generate a reply and I don't necessarily expect a reply from the data I send.

I am having a bit of a struggle implementing this with spring-integration.
I managed to get something that sort of but not quite works by doing:

```
    public static IntegrationFlow RegisterFeedFlow(final IntegrationFlowContext flowContext,
            final String id, final String host, final int port) {
        IntegrationFlow feedFlow = f -> f
                .handle(Tcp
                        .outboundGateway(Tcp.netClient(host, port).serializer(TcpCodecs.crlf())
                                .deserializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader1()))
                        .remoteTimeout(m -> 5000))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString()).handle(System.out::println);


        flowContext.registration(feedFlow).id(id).register();

        return feedFlow;
    }
```

What is missing here is:

1. TLS.
2. Because I am using Tcp.outboundGateway() it always expects a reply for the data I send. I don't want this.

I assume that I could automatically encode and decode the json by putting something in .serializer() and .deserializer(). Is this assumption correct?

How would I implement this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Gitter66Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Gitter66Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean privateFeedClient() {
        TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean fb = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean("client");
        fb.setHost("localhost");
        fb.setPort(1234);
        fb.setSerializer(TcpCodecs.crlf());
        fb.setDeserializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader1());
        fb.setSslContextSupport(new DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport("keystore.ks",
                "trustStore.ks", "keyStorePassword", "trustStorePassword"));
        return fb;
    }

    @Bean
    public TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean privateFeedServer() {
        TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean fb = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean("server");
        fb.setPort(1234);
        fb.setSerializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader1());
        fb.setDeserializer(TcpCodecs.crlf());
        fb.setSslContextSupport(new DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport("keystore.ks",
                "trustStore.ks", "keyStorePassword", "trustStorePassword"));
        return fb;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flowOut(AbstractClientConnectionFactory cf) {
        return f -> f.handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(cf));
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flowIn(AbstractServerConnectionFactory cf) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(cf))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .handle(System.out::println)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(@Qualifier("flowOut.input") MessageChannel channel) {
        return args -> {
            channel.send(new GenericMessage<>("foo"));
        };
    }

}
```

Result:

```
GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={ip_tcp_remotePort=62471, ...
```

**EDIT**

You can, of course, register the flows dynmically as you have in your question. To register the factories dynamically:

```java
    private TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean privateFeedClient(String host, int port) {
        TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean fb = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean("client");
        fb.setHost(host);
        fb.setPort(port);
        fb.setSerializer(TcpCodecs.crlf());
        fb.setDeserializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader1());
        fb.setSslContextSupport(new DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport("keystore.ks",
                "trustStore.ks", "keyStorePassword", "trustStorePassword"));
        return fb;
    }

    private TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean privateFeedServer(int port) {
        TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean fb = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean("server");
        fb.setPort(1234);
        fb.setSerializer(TcpCodecs.lengthHeader1());
        fb.setDeserializer(TcpCodecs.crlf());
        fb.setSslContextSupport(new DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport("keystore.ks",
                "trustStore.ks", "keyStorePassword", "trustStorePassword"));
        return fb;
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(GenericApplicationContext context) {

        return args -> {
            TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean server = privateFeedServer(1234);
            context.registerBean("server", TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean.class,
                    () -> server);
            TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean client = privateFeedClient("localhost", 1234);
            context.registerBean("client", TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean.class,
                    () -> client);
            // register flows
        };
    }
```

Comment: How would I, with this solution, A) Dynamically set the host and port B) Create a second feed client (Let's call it publicFeedClient)?

Comment: The first parameter to context.registerBean is what I would put in my `@Qualifier` to get the bean, right? Can I even use the `@Bean` annotation this way or would I have to fetch the bean through the application context? I'm still learning Spring here.

Comment: You cannot use `@Bean` for dynamic registrations. You should fetch the bean from the context so that it is properly initialized by Spring.